# calling a webservice in android

Tags: android

I have a webservice in android application which i have to call.The response of the webservice is as follows

```
<vmsc>
<response code="0" message="Success"/>
−
<responsedata>
−
<productcategories>
−
<productcategory>
<id>1</id>
<title>Celebrities</title>
<description>Celebrities</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>2</id>
<title>Music</title>
<description>Music</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>3</id>
<title>Sports</title>
<description>Sports</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>4</id>
<title>Fashion</title>
<description>Fashion</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>5</id>
<title>Religion</title>
<description>Religion</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>6</id>
<title>Others</title>
<description>Others</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>7</id>
<title>Education</title>
<description>Education</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>8</id>
<title>Charity</title>
<description>Charity</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>9</id>
<title>Film</title>
<description>Film</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
−
<productcategory>
<id>10</id>
<title>Health</title>
<description>Health</description>
<image>
        </image>
</productcategory>
</productcategories>
</responsedata>
</vmsc>
```

Can anyone tell how should i call this webservice...

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: email your concerns to team@stackoverflow.com please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tutorial serie:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-series-from-sql-php-to-xml-json-to-android-listview/

Comment: programmer i have looked at the link

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) and [this](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) out.

This is KSOAP2 library to interact with webservices.